# Batch file with choosing Y/N

Tags: batch-file

Please help, I'm a beginner and I need to create batch-file to delete log-files. But before delete I need to ask user to delete the last log-file or all log-files.

I tried to implement it like:

```
set /P PARAM_VALUE=Remove only the last log file?(Y/N)?  

if /I "%PARAM_VALUE%"=="y" goto DeleteLast
if /I "%PARAM_VALUE%"=="n" goto DeleteAll
```

But in this case I can enter any values, I need to avoid an others character except `Y,y,N,n`. 
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solutionі in this case is using the [CHOICE](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php) command. 
This tool allows users to select one item from a list of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

Syntax: `CHOICE [ /C choices ] [ /N ] [ /CS ] [ /T timeout /D choice ] [ /M text ]`

Parameter List:

- **/C choices**    Specifies the list of choices to be created. Default list for English versions is `YN`
- **/N**  Hides the list of choices in the prompt. The message before the prompt is displayed and the choices are still enabled.
- **/CS** Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected. By default, the utility is case-insensitive. *Note: DOS and NT Resource Kit versions use `/S` instead*
- **/T timeout**       The number of seconds to pause before a default choice
  is made. Acceptable values are from 0 to 9999.
  If 0 is specified, there will be no pause and the default choice is selected.
  *Note: DOS and NT Resource Kit versions use `/T:default,timeout` instead.*
- **/D default**       Specifies the default choice after timeout seconds.
  Character must be in the set of choices specified by `/C` option and must also specify timeout with `/T`.
  *Note: DOS and NT Resource Kit versions use `/T:default,timeout` instead.*
- **/M text**      Specifies the message to be displayed before the prompt.
  If not specified, the utility displays only a prompt.

For your problem try to use something like:

```
choice /C:YN /M:"Remove only the last log file? [YN]"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO DeleteLast
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO DeleteAll
GOTO next

:DeleteAll
rem delete all

:DeleteLast
rem delete last

:next
rem continue work with Batch file
```

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting,I didn't hear about this command before

Comment: Thank you @Megatron. It is working. And it was very simple. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can just catch all other inputs like this:

```
:CONFIRM
if /i "%PARAMVALUE%"=="y" goto DeleteLast
if /i "%PARAMVALUE%"=="n" goto DeleteAll
echo Please enter only Y/y or N/n!
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto CONFIRM
```

I used this too for my own scripts and it works wonderfully and is super easy!

Answer (score 0):

The delete command already offers a prompt N/y

**EDIT**

```
del /p
```

type `del /?` in console for more information

**UPDATE**

you can test with this example:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL

Echo:
Echo  /!\ Creating a bunch of empty files /!\
echo  Press any key to continue or CTRL-C to exit...
Pause>nul

for /L %%A in (1,1,4) do (copy /y NUL _temp_file_%%A.ext)

Echo:
Echo  /!\ Deleting a bunch of empty files with command prompt /!\
echo  Press any key to continue or CTRL-C to exit...
Pause>nul

del /p "_temp_file_?.ext"

Echo:
Pause>nul|(echo  Press any key to exit...)
```

Comment: Could you please more describe it? Thx